# assignment operator in c++

Tags: c++

let's assume I have some class A and derived from it B:
I want to write `operator=` for B (let's assume that I have `operator=` in my A class)
right way to do this:

```
B& B::operator=(const B& rhs)
{
if(this == &rhs) return *this;
((A&) *this) = rhs; //<-question
//some other options
return *this
}
```

what is the difference if I write

```
((A) *this) = rhs;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Use if (this != &rhs) instead of if(this == &rhs).

Comment: @DumbCoder: It's supposed to catch `x == x;` and currently does so correctly.  I disagree with your proposed change.

Comment: @Ben Voight, I think DumbCoder is suggesting the OP should change his `if` to check for non-self assignment and do the copying work, then handle self assignment in the `else` part. Since self-assignment is not (or at least shouldn't be) the normal use case this would mean the `if` almost always succeeds thus preventing a branch instruction and associated pipeline flushes.

Comment: Personally I prefer: `static_cast<A*>(this)->operator=(rhs);`

Comment: @Praetorian: premature optimization at its finest.  The compiler decides which branch goes where, and the pipeline flush occurs not when a branch is taken but when it is mispredicted (on any modern CPU).

Comment: @Martin: I try never to use a cast when an implicit conversion exists, because casts can inhibit legitimate compiler warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second code would copy just the `A` part (slicing) of `*this` into a temporary variable, assign it, and throw it away.  Not very helpful.

I would instead write that line as:

```
A::operator=(rhs);
```

which makes it very clear that it is invoking the base class version.

Cast-and-assign could be better in a template situation where you don't actually know what your base class is, and whether it has an `operator=` member or friend or what.

In that case:

```
A* basethis = this;
*basethis = rhs;
```

is easier to read and understand.

Comment: a "temporary variable, assign it, and throw it away" ...? are you kidding me? he put 'this' in as the pointer source..

Comment: @ianmac45: Ben Voigt is correct. The OP's second code does in fact create a copy of `*this` because `((A) *this) = rhs` is equivalent to `static_cast<A>(*this) = rhs` which in this case is equivalent to `A(*this).operator=(rhs)` (C++ standard 5.2.9/2). A temporary `A` is created, then the assignment operator is called on it passing `rhs` as an argument, then the temporary is destructed.

Comment: @ianmac45: Not kidding you at all.  The original has a temporary variable too, but in the original the temporary variable has type *reference-to-A* (A&), so writing to the temporary changes `*this`.  The second one is type `A`, not a reference, so writing to the temporary changes only the temporary.

Comment: @In silico: please explain why do I create tmp object in second version?

Comment: @rookie: `((A) *this) = rhs` is equivalent to `static_cast<A>(*this) = rhs` by C++ standard 5.4/5. Then, by C++ standard 5.2.9/2, that expression is equivalent to `A(*this).operator=(rhs)`. The expression `A(*this)` creates a temporary of type `A` passing `*this` to `A`'s copy constructor. The expression `.operator=(rhs)` that comes right after that calls `A`'s assignment operator. When the assignment operator returns, the temporary is destructed.

Comment: @rookie: On the other hand, the expression `((A&) *this) = rhs` does the exact same thing, but instead of creating a temporary `A`, it creates a temporary `A&`, which is a reference, which is an alias to another object. So calling `operator=()` on a variable of type `A&` calls `operator=()` on the original object (in this case, `*this`) as though it was type `A`, but does not copy nor destruct the original object.